# How to write typescript definition of 3rd party module so that it I can import anything

Tags: typescript, es6-modules, typescript-definitions

I have a 3rd party library without typescript definitions.

Can I write module declaration that will allow me to import anything from that module?

```
import { Anything } from 'untypedexternalmodule';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Just add a `global.d.ts` file to your project containing

```
declare module 'untypedexternalmodule';
```

If you try running the code you wrote you will get information asking you to do exactly this.